# Seleccionar columnas de archivo CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

tengo un archivo llamado `gdp-vs-happiness.csv` contiene bastantes paises y su información con GDP y Happiness de distintos años.
Ocupo solo algunos paises del años 2015 por lo que filtré para que únicamente mostrara el años 2015

```
import pandas as pd
countries = pd.read_csv('gdp-vs-happiness.csv')
countries = countries[countries.Year == 2015]
```

Entonces la tabla luce algo mas o menos así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces por ejemplo si solo necesito datos de Argentina, Mexico y Panama es donde estoy atorado.
He estado separando cada pais por separado pero quería ver si hay alguna forma en que se puedan quedar solo los paises que voy a ocupar.

```
#Ejemplo
argentina = america[america.Entity == 'Argentina']
mexico = america[america.Entity == 'Mexico']
```

Comment: El archivo gdp-vs-happiness.csv es libre o privado, te lo pregunto para ver si lo compartes (archivo o url) para poder ver tu problema (o un archivo similar) y darte una solucion. gracias.

Comment: Es publico obtenido de Our World in Data en [enlace](https://ourworldindata.org/happiness-and-life-satisfaction#the-link-across-countries) en la sección the link across countries, tiene algunos cambios como por ejemplo Norte America y Sudamerica se toma como America, GDP aparece con un nombre mas largo igual que con Happiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paises = america[america.Entity.isin(['Argentina', 'Mexico'])]
```

o una traerlos de una lista:

```
listaPaises = ['Argentina', 'Mexico']

paises = america[america.Entity.isin(listaPaises)]
```

Comment: Gracias, si funcionó